# Prevent initializer in rake tasks and rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with Rails and Websockets listening.

I created an initializer which starts listening on those websockets, so, when I push in production with Capistrano, the server doesn't stop listening on those Sockets for a long time.

But, when I use something like `rails c`, `rake db:migrate` or something else, the initializer is called (I know this is normal), and I want to prevent this initializer processing on my `rails c` or `rake` tasks. PS : I use `unicorn` in production.

Do you know how to prevent the initializer processing when it is not called by a unicorn launching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about passing an arg like:

```
NOSOCK=true bundle exec rails c
```

and in your initializer:

```
unless ENV['NOSOCK']
  #socket code
end
```

Comment: Can i use both `NOSOCK=true` and `RAILS_ENV=production` ? Like `NOSOCK=true RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c`

Comment: sure, you just add a list of ENV vars

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to not launch your listening on websockets process from an initializer. Start it manually or some another way. If you are using Capistrano you may start this process on deploy.